# "Heads or Tails?" guessing game in Python

Tags: python, beginner, game, python-2.x

I'm pretty new to coding and I want to get an opinion on my coding. I am learning Python and I made a really simple heads and tails guessing game.

```
import random
import time
import easygui
import sys
while True:
    rand = random.choice(["Heads", "Tails"])
    firstguess = raw_input("Guess Heads or Tails: ")
    if firstguess == rand:
        print "Wow you win"
    else:
        print "That is wrong you suck so bad lol."
    time.sleep(2)
    answer = easygui.buttonbox("Play again?", choices=["Yes","No"])
    if answer == "Yes":
        easygui.msgbox("Ok")
    else:
        break

easygui.msgbox("Ok, see you later!")
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: You are doing fine. My first program ever was a guessing game like this.  Keep it up.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you mixing `raw_input()` with `easygui`?  That's a suboptimal user experience.

`sys.exit(0)` at the end is superfluous, but harmless.